# Expression for ways of choosing k out of n objects placed in a circle such that r of them are consecutive.

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $n$ distinct objects in a circle. How many ways are there to select $k$ of these objects so that there exists atleast $r$ selected objects which occur consecutively?

For example, suppose I have to choose 3 out of 7 object numbered $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$ and arranged in a circle such there exists $2$ of them which are consecutive. Then there are $28$ possible sets:

$$
(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,2,6),(1,2,7),(1,3,4),(1,3,7),\\
(1,4,5),(1,4,7),(1,5,6),(1,5,7),(1,6,7),(2,3,4),(2,3,5),\\
(2,3,6),(2,3,7),(2,4,5),(2,5,6),(2,6,7),(3,4,5),(3,4,6),\\
(3,4,7),(3,5,6),(3,6,7),(4,5,6),(4,5,7),(4,6,7),(5,6,7). $$

Note that the sets $(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,6),(2,4,6),(2,4,7),(2,5,7),(3,5,7)$ are not included here.

I have been struggling with this problem for 3 days now and I cant solve this. Any help or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: In response to the queries of @trueblueanil:

1. I have listed all possible sets which have atleast 2 consecutive selections in them. For example, (1,2,3) has (1,2) and (2,3) which are consecutive. Similarly, (1,5,6) has only (5,6) which is consecutive. However, (1,3,5) has no 2 consecutive entries.
2. All the seven objects are placed in a circle. Out of these 7 object, 3 are picked. The condition on them is that atleast 2 out of the 3 picked must be consecutive in the circle.

Edit 2: @Bulbasaur, could you elaborate on inclusion-exclusion or provide a link which I could check to read up on it?

Comment: Hint= Inclusion-exclusion

Comment: **1.** What have you tried to list ? They are neither all possible triples, nor those satisfying your stipulation. **2.** It is unclear whether your stipulation is *exactly* two consecutive or *at least* two consecutive. **3.** Pl clarify

Comment: @trueblueanil the *intentional* (i.e. not a mistake ?) inclusion of $(1,2,3)$ in his offered example resolves your #2, in my opinion.  The difficulty here is the confrontation between [*answer* *police* : showing work, problem background...] and the difficulty for the inexperienced to implement Inclusion-Exclusion.  Personally, in more than one mathSE question, I posted a flawed Inclusion-Exclusion answer until my intuition got stretched.  What is a responder supposed to do, post 8 consecutive 500 character comments giving a reasonable guide?

Comment: @Bulbasaur See my last comment.  If this question isn't an indication that the mathSE protocol needs an overhaul, I don't know what is.

Comment: Also, are 1-7 placed in a circle, and we are choosing $3$ and listing the way you have done, or are we placing the *chosen* triple in a circle. Your question needs to be much more precise if it is to get any meaningful response.

Comment: @MikeEarnest In your now-deleted attempt, if there are at least $r$ consecutive objects, shouldn't there be at least $r - 1$ consecutive pairs? In your sanity check, you used one consecutive pair for two consecutive objects, which makes sense, only your $r$ corresponded to Dhruv Pratap Singh's $r - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, I made quite a silly mistake. The actual answer is
$$
\sum_{b=1}^{k-r+1}\frac nb\binom{n-k-1}{b-1}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor (k-b)/(r-1)\rfloor}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{b}i\binom{k-1-i(r-1)}{b-1},
$$
but I do not have the time/energy to write out an answer explicating that.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Just a clarification. In the inner summation (the one over $i$), $i$ may become larger than $b$. In those cases, I assumed $ \binom{b}{i}=0$. Is that your assumption as well?

Comment: @DhruvPratapSingh Yes indeed! BTW, here is a rough sketch of the proof. As in my deleted answer, the $b$ variable represents the number of blocks. The inner summation counts the number of ways to distribute $k$ selected items into these $b$ groups, so that at least one group gets $r$ or more, using the principle of inclusion exclusion. Also, [this computer program](https://replit.com/@mearnest/Subsets-of-a-circle-with-r-consecutive#main.py) confirms the formula is correct up to $n=18$, so I think it is likely I made no mistakes.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you so much for your help.